# Unable to return results for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

My goal is to only show purchase orders that haven't received all their product yet.

I have a master table called `test_po` and two other tables `test_po_bom`, `test_rog_bom`.  The `test_po_bom` and `test_rog_bom` tables are where I'm storing the list of products.  `test_po_bom` is the list of products I've ordered, `test_rog_bom` is the list of products I've received.

Basically: `loop purchase_orders WHERE products_received < products_ordered`

**Table Structure:**

```
table `test_po`: `ID`, `vendor_ID`
table `test_po_bom`: `ID`, `po_ID`, `product_ID`, `quantity`
table `test_rog_bom`: `ID`, `po_ID`, `product_ID`, `quantity`
```

**Code:**

```
$SQL = "SELECT
        *,
        test_po.ID AS test_po_ID
      FROM
        test_po
      LEFT JOIN test_po_bom ON test_po_bom.po_ID=test_po.ID
      LEFT JOIN test_rog_bom ON test_rog_bom.po_ID=test_po.ID
      WHERE
        (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM test_rog_bom WHERE po_ID=test_po.ID) < (SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM test_po_bom WHERE po_ID=test_po.ID)";

$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['test_po_ID'].'<br>';
}
```

It doesn't spit out anything, and I've tried many different variations but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: If you get no output, then you're getting no results. Try debugging the query separately.

Comment: For starters, use table aliases. They make your query a lot more readable, and are required for complex joins.

Comment: @NateC-K "required" is a strong word IMO. I agree that they are very much needed but docs&specs define and differentiate these words required/must/can/should very well.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: How else are you going to join a table to itself? I'd like to know if there's some other syntax that makes this possible.

Comment: That would be one case when you are *required* to alias at least one of the occurrences but the notion of complex joins span a lot more than self-joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with your query.  Don't use `*` and instead specify the desired columns.  The following solution uses aliases to help make your code more readable, especially with similar names.  You will also notice [HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html) instead of WHERE.

```
SELECT 
    p.ID as PO_ID
     ,p.VENDOR_ID
     ,pb.product_ID as PRODUCT_ID
     ,SUM(pb.quantity) as QUANTITY_ORDERED
     ,SUM(rb.quantity) as QUANTITY_RECEIVED
FROM test_po as p
LEFT JOIN test_po_bom as pb ON pb.po_ID = p.ID
LEFT JOIN test_rog_bom as rb ON rb.po_ID = p.ID
GROUP BY
    p.ID
     ,p.VENDOR_ID
     ,pb.product_ID
HAVING SUM(rb.quantity) < SUM(pb.quantity)
```

Comment: You nailed it, thank you very much!  You guys always amaze me at how quickly you can understand a question and be able to return a correct answer in a matter of minutes.  I am much impressed, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS UNTESTED CODE.** I apologize for posting untested code but I can't test it right now, and I think it demonstrates some things for you to try differently even if it's not exactly correct.

Try this:

```
select po.ID, po_bom.quant n_ordered, rog_bom.quant n_received
from test_po po
left join (select po_ID, sum(quantity) as quant from test_po_bom group by po_ID) po_bom
  on po.ID = po_bom.po_ID
left join (select po_ID, sum(quantity) as quant from test_rog_bom group by po_ID) rog_bom
  on po.ID = rog_bom.po_ID
where coalesce(rog_bom.quant, 0) < coalesce(po_bom.quant, 0);
```

This changes a few things from how you were doing them:

- Uses table aliases to clearly specify which references refer to the same table row.
- Uses group by to aggregate the sums by ID.
- Uses coalesce to deal with situation where at least one of your tables (probably test_rog_bom) has no rows for an ID. I suspect this was actually the source of your problem in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Nate, you totally helped out!  I've been trying to figure how to include null rows with left joins and coalesce totally answered it.